# How can I continue using CEPT now that the authors have withdrawn support?

Tags: windows

Legitimate users of Creative Elements Power Tools (CEPT) have a problem because the registration code can no longer be refreshed since Creative no longer support the product, rendering the software useless.

How can I continue using CEPT now that the authors have withdrawn support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to roll back the clock to the date that the software was first installed.  This can be done manually but is cumbersome. Better to write a small batch script to do the job.  The software continues to function after the date has been reset to today's date.

```
SET BackupDate=%date%    
ECHO Today's Date backed up to: %BackupDate%

:: This echo will show you the date format to be used in the next line,
:: or you can simply look at the notification tray.
:: The date itself has to be when you first installed the software.

PAUSE

DATE 2009-05-23

:: CEPT consists of a number of exe files of which FileTypeDoctor is one.
:: Look in Program Files to find the others.

START "" "C:\Program Files\Creative Element Power Tools\File Type Doctor.exe"

:: Reset today's date.

DATE  %BackupDate%
```

Comment: I like it.  Though one thing to note is, if you have the program open for more than one day, or over midnight, you will restore the wrong date.  Probably not a big issue for this sort of program.

Comment: @dsolimano  How so? The only way you can get a wrong date is if midnight falls in the few milliseconds of the batch process.

Comment: that's exactly the scenario that worries me.  Being a computer programmer by day, I always think in terms of the unlikely scenario (e.g. [One in a million is next Tuesday](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/03/30/104165.aspx))

Comment: Yep, that's prudent and good practice. Kick off with a PAUSE conditional on the time of night.